# display string with markup in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a string with the following format :

```
" Data\r\n  more data <DIV> "
```

I want to display this string exactly including the leading spaces and line breaks.

```
" Data
   more data <DIV> "
```

I am currently using jquery to display this like

```
$("<small class='text-success'></small>").text(theString)
```

This nicely encodes any HTML elements to display but doesn't work for the leading spaces or line breaks.

I tried replacing the spaces with non breaking spaces but then the text method also encodes that too.

Is there a way to do this without manually encoding the whole string?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> This nicely encodes any HTML elements to display but doesn't work for the leading spaces or line breaks.

To do that, you'd want to use the [`white-space`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/white-space) CSS property with the value `pre`, `preline`, or `pre-wrap` (but probably just `pre`). Ideally, do that by giving it a class you apply the styling to:

CSS:

```css
.preformatted {
    white-space: pre;
}
```

and then

```js
$("<small class='text-success preformatted'></small>").text(theString)
```

Example:

```js
var theString = " Data\r\n  more data <DIV> ";
$("<small class='text-success preformatted'></small>").text(theString).appendTo(document.body);
```

```css
.preformatted {
  white-space: pre;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

But if necessary, you can do it inline:

```
$("<small class='text-success'></small>").css("white-space", "pre").text(theString)
```

Example:

```js
var theString = " Data\r\n  more data <DIV> ";
$("<small class='text-success'></small>").css("white-space", "pre").text(theString).appendTo(document.body);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: This is spot on, I changed the small element to a pre and didn't need the white-space property

Answer (score 0):

You can use template literals to use exact strings as it is

```
var string= `Data
             more data <DIV>`;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try replace `"\r\n"` with `"<br/>"`. That should prolly work.